# Using Windows Integrated Authentication when connecting to db4o in .net?

Tags: .net, windows-authentication, db4o

When opening a client against a db40 server it seems to expect a user name and password

```
Db4oFactory.OpenClient(string hostName, int port, string user, string password);
```

Is there any way of using windows integrated instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, no way to do that! The username/password verification is pretty simple and was never planned to be extensible (Windows Native, LDAP, whatever) on db4o.